# MySQL selecting a field as an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have two tables:

```
teachers(teacher_id, name, ... )
teach_subjects(teacher_id, subject_id, ... )
```

In `teach_subject` the `teacher_id` is not unique since a teacher can teach more than one subject.

What I want, is to select a list of teachers together with the subjects they teach.
The SQL-query I use is

```
SELECT teacher_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT subject_id SEPARATOR ',') AS subjects, [select some more here]
FROM teachers LEFT JOIN teach_subjects USING(teacher_id)
GROUP BY teacher_id;
```

This selects the ids of subjects as a string for each teacher.
In PHP I use `explode` to get an array of subject ids for each teacher. This works fine, but *I am wonder if this is really the way I have to go**?***

I only see one other way: Split the query into two queries (one for selecting the teacher data, one for selecting the subjects)

**Edit:** Not grouping the data and so getting the rows multiple times with only different `subject_id` is not an option, due to I'm selecting some other *big* data, so I get a too big overhead.

**Notice**: This is just a simplification of the queries I really use. I just want to keep it simple for now.

Comment: Break your array up into a string, and use "IN ([subject1],[subject2])" and so on.

Comment: This can be done without using group_concat, just order your results by teacher id and in php code put logic to show teacher only once per group

Comment: The problem is, that I selecting more than juste the teacher id. I dont think is a good idea to select 1kb text 5 times only because there is alwas a diffrent subject id at the end. But yes, if the id where the only other data i wold have considered this too.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I dont see the connection to my question. I dont want to filter by the subjects.

Comment: I was taking it that you wanted a unique record for each subject the teacher teaches.  It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I think that what you are doing now is much better than the alternative you are contemplating.